# Get Children Recursively in Sitecore CMS .NET

Tags: sitecore

Does anyone know how to recursively get the children of an item in a Sitecore web control?  I'd rather not use Sitecore query because some of my paths have dashes in them which really screws things up.  The Sitecore.Context.Item.getChildren() and Sitecore.Context.Item.Children property both returned just the top level children.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Sitecore, looks like the way to do this is Item.Axes.GetDescendants()

Comment: Yes it is the best performed way.

Comment: Be careful, because you never know how many children there are, this can become an expensive function.

Comment: Don't use this approach in case if you are getting Template list or other, that time you will get unnecessary Standard values. There after you have to spent time to skip std. value. So before move forward clear your requirements.

Comment: @User Yes, this will retrieve all items and since Standard Values is an item that would be expected behavior.

Comment: It should be noted as @Anicho mentions that this can get really nasty if returning lots of items. Anything over 100 will perform terribly. I can't remember what my use case was, but in general you are better off using `Sitecore.Search` which uses Lucene indexes. Then just go to the Sitecore database for what you absolutely need.